# Hover effect on multiple boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have multiple boxes, I want to apply hover effect to each, that when I hover a single one, all other boxes should appear more transparent, giving a more focusing effect.
I need to accomplish it with some sort of slow transition effects.

I've tried to make it as following but it seems not working well

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmed2222/rSNS5/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="thumb"> </div>
    <div class="thumb"> </div>
    <div class="thumb"> </div>
    <div class="thumb"> </div>
    <div class="thumb"> </div>  
    <div class="thumb"> </div>
    <div class="thumb"> </div>
    <div class="thumb"> </div>
    <div class="thumb"> </div>
 <div>
```

---

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.thumb {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #000;  
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $('.thumb').hover(function () {
      $(this).css({"opacity":"1"});
      $('.thumb').not(this).animate({"opacity":"0.3"}, 1000);
    },
    function () {
      $('.thumb').css({"opacity":"1"});
    });
});
```

**Any idea, why my code is not working?**

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you provided... assuming you are trying to do what it appears you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated with jsfiddle link , the code above doesn't work correct

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have js or css. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/KfARr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real problem that I noticed with your original solution is that sometimes the animations that were running were causing problems when you move from one item to another quickly. Was this the problem you wanted to address? If so, you can put `stop()`s to stop the animation.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rSNS5/4/

```
$(function() {
    $('.thumb').hover(function () {
      $('.thumb').stop();
      $(this).css({"opacity":"1"});
      $('.thumb').not(this).animate({"opacity":"0.3"}, 1000);
    },
    function () {
      $('.thumb').stop().css({"opacity":"1"});
    });
});
```

Comment: GREAT ! Just what I was looking for. I've added a simple extra effect and now it rocks ! Thanks much :)

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmed2222/rSNS5/6/

Answer (score 1):

No need for javascript to achieve this, pure css will do:

```
.container:hover .thumb {
    opacity: .5;
}

.container:hover .thumb:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and a fiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/pPWgq/

**edit:**
and with the transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/pPWgq/1/

just added this:

```
.thumb {
   ...
   transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Comment: OP said: "I need to accomplish it with some sort of slow transition effects."

Comment: @PeterVR very nice job! Note that when you hover the container without hovering any of the thumbs they're all becoming transparent. which is not desired I beleive

Comment: Nice idea for targeting the container ! I still want it with JS to work on older browsers. I'll try to play around with this idea. Thanks